# Django template system standalone

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, django-settings

I am trying to use the Django template system as a tool in a python script to output files. I need no other component of the Django framework.

I followed the instructions to [configure the template system for standalone mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#configuring-the-template-system-in-standalone-mode), but when I try to use `template.loader.render_to_string()`, `template.loader.get_template()`, or `template.render(Content())` I get back the `AppRegistryNotReady` exception:

```
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I have the following `settings.configure()` call as described in the docs:

```
settings.configure(
    DEBUG=DEBUG,
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True,
    TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
        POSTS_DIR,
        TEMPLATES_DIR,
        PAGES_DIR,
    ),
)
```

And I tried adding in `INSTALLED_APPS=()` as well, same problem. I just want to use the templating system. I don't need anything except for template loaders so I can `extend` templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that this error is thrown from `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader`. Try to add `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting:

```
settings.configure(
    DEBUG=DEBUG,
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True,
    TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
        POSTS_DIR,
        TEMPLATES_DIR,
        PAGES_DIR,
    ),
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS=('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` was enabled by default. Specifying the `filesystem.loader` did the trick!

Answer (score 6):

If your code is truly standalone you have to invoke `django.setup()`:

```
import os
import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

settings.configure(
    TEMPLATES=[{
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))],  # script dir
    }]
)
django.setup()

message = render_to_string(
    'mail_template.html',
    {'variable1337': 1337}
)
print(message)
```

Also, `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is deprecated. The current accepted answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 3):

For those who came here from django 1.10, and like me, want to test the Django Template Language with unittest, u need to use the Engine Class.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/src$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 10 2016, 08:21:44) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
.>>> from django.template import Engine, Context
.>>> _template = Engine().from_string('my name {{ name }}')
.>>> _context = Context({'name':'Claudio Santos'})
.>>> _template.render(_context)
'my name Claudio Santos'
```

Refences:

[Upgrading Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.10/ref/templates/upgrading/)

[The Engine Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Engine)

[Using Settings without DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module)